# ( C ) Best way to step x number of times forward in the ASCII-chart but still keeping it between a-z?

Tags: c, while-loop, ascii

Basically you enter a word and then a number. The program takes each character and steps  ahead in ASCII. Ex. "hello" and the number 1 returns "ifmmp".
Now if i were to enter a number greater than the ASCII-value of the character and the number combined, i would get characters that arent a-z. To keep it at a-z i made a while loop and my question is:

Can i do this without looping 5000 times if i enter a value of ~5000?

(word, number, answer and x are declared earlier)

```
int countNumber = word[x];
int countComplete = word[x];    

if(word[x] + number > 122){
    while(countNumber != number) {
        if(countComplete == 122){
            countComplete = 97;
            countNumber++;
        }
        else{
            countNumber++;
            countComplete++;
        }
    }
    answer[x] = countComplete;
    x++;
}
else{
    answer[x] = word[x] + number;
    x++;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what a [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is?

Comment: `(letter - 'a' + number) % ('z' + 1 - 'a') + 'a'`

Comment: @zch: I think you meant ('z'-'a'+1)

Comment: @ScottHunter, right, classical fencepost error.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, my.

First off, the only numbers that matter are 0..25; anything else just does extra loops through the whole alphabet.  So start by replacing number with number%26.

But this suggests that you can eliminate the loop entirely.  If the ASCII codes in question were from 0..25, then you could just replace ASCII code x with (x+number)%26.  Instead, you have map x to that range by subtracting the ASCII code of a, perform the math just described, and then add that code back.

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop to increment each value by one is not what you want… you ant a single accumulation followed by a single wraparound (if the wraparound is needed).

First thing to do is to reduce the large number to the smallest number that would still have the same result. Since there are only 26 values before wraparound, you can simply set `number = number % 26;` or, more generically, `number = number % (1 + 'z' - 'a');`

Next, do the accumulation; `answer[x] = word[x] + number;`

Finally handle wrap-around: `if ([answer[x] > 'z') answer[x] = answer[x] + 'a' - 'z';`

Answer (score 0):

modify the char so that the ascii char 'a' is zero, add your value and then make % 26

like that:

```
answer[x] = (word[x]-'a'+number)%26+'a';
```

Comment: But now answer[x] could be 0, which isn't one of the desired ASCII codes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot! Figured out the math before but had no idea how to do it in code. Didnt know v1%v2 divided and returned the remainder.

Cheers for the answers :)